# Best way to disable ViewPager paging

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scroll-paging

I'm developing an app which have a `ViewPager` as a menu. Each `fragment` has a bunch of child views which can be `ListView`, `ScrollView`, `LinearLayout`, etc...
One of this `fragments` have a **settings** button which toggles a settings panel (`LinearLayout` wrapper) with a `ScrollView` and some `LinearLayout` (buttons) and `SeekBar` as childs. This **settings** panel is animated with a slide up or down animation (when dismissed) and when it's visible I disable the `ViewPager` paging:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!pagingEnabled && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!pagingEnabled && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}

public boolean isPagingEnabled() {
    return pagingEnabled;
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean pagingEnabled) {
    this.pagingEnabled = pagingEnabled;
}
```

But this came with a problem, every time the panel is up all it child views wouldn't receive the `OnTouchEvent` and that's why I've added a `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener`:

```
protected class YScrollDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        Log.i(C.TAG, "distanceX " + distanceX + " distanceY " + distanceY);
        return Math.abs(distanceY) < Math.abs(distanceX);
    }
}
```

and changed my `ViewPager` `onInterceptTouchEvent` to:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!pagingEnabled && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && (mGestureDetector != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}
```

This works, the panel buttons receive their onClick, the ListView swipes, etc... but this doesn't work so perfect because `Math.abs(distanceY) < Math.abs(distanceX)` it's not that accurate. If I fast swipe up and down or diagonally or if I touch a button with a minor swipe the `onInterceptTouchEvent` will return `true` because `mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)` will return `true` too.
After some google search I came across this:

```
viewPager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

And I tried something like this:

```
myListView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        viewPager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

And it works really well because `ViewPager.onInterceptTouchEvent` it's called first with `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and then `myListView.setOnTouchListener` it's called right after and disallows the remaining `MotionEvent` actions (MOVE and UP) and I can fast swipe up, down, sides ways, etc. The `ViewPager` wont page but the `ListView` swipes like a charm.

But a problem still remains, I've to add this `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` to all child views `onTouchEvent`, and it's not elegant code.
So my question is, I am on the right path? Is there anyway to avoid adding this listener to all the panel child views (of course if I have to I'll do it in the most generic way)?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Disabling paging should be as simple as returning `false` from both `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent`. You shouldn't need extra gesture detection to get around the `ViewPager`. Extend `ViewPager` like this:

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager {
    private boolean pagingEnabled = true;

    public MyViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean pagingEnabled) {
        this.pagingEnabled = pagingEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return pagingEnabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return pagingEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

I use the same thing (with a different name) for the same reason in one of my apps and it definitely works.

Comment: I'm so stupid, of course I must return false eheh! If I return true I'll be stealing the motion events from the children and the events wouldn't be dispatched to the ViewGroup through onTouchEvent(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can **disable paging** in  your **viewpager**  by simply calling
this method on your viewpager

> *view_pager.**setUserInputEnabled(false)***

[Read more](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#setUserInputEnabled(boolean))